where MYSQL database tables created for below keycloak docker command
where MYSQL database tables created for below keycloak docker command
docker run -p 9090:8080 --name keycloak --net keycloak-network -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -e DB_VENDOR=MYSQL -e DB_ADDR=jdbc:mysql://root@localhost:3306/keycloak -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_DATABASE=keycloak -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=keycloak  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest start-dev
I am able to save the users without any issues. but I wanted to see tables and data created by keycloak
Below is keycloack log in docker
2024-08-14 02:50:42,717 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_748127, Site name: null
2024-08-14 02:50:42,988 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventLis
tener
2024-08-14 02:50:43,120 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (main) KC-SERVICES0050: Initializing master realm
2024-08-14 02:50:47,266 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (main) KC-SERVICES0009: Added user 'admin' to realm 'master'
2024-08-14 02:50:47,498 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Keycloak 25.0.2 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.8.5) started in 21.751s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080. Management interface
 listening on http://0.0.0.0:9000.
2024-08-14 02:50:47,499 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile dev activated.
2024-08-14 02:50:47,499 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-h2, keycloak, logging-gelf, narayana-jta, reactive-routes, resteasy-rea
ctive, resteasy-reactive-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]

wanted to see tables and data created by keycloak.

I don't fully understand hiw this question is related to programming or software development. This is useful information for whoever is deploying or operating keycloak SSO, but not relevant from a programming point of view.

By default, data is stored in a file, not a database when using start-dev command.
It would be best to use Docker Compose to run a separate mysql container then link keycloak to that by using a separate hostname than localhost, using --db flags to specify connection details or environment variables starting with KC_DB
